# All operator in mongo using Spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

How can I use @Query annotation in spring to query an array in mongo Document.
eg:

```
user_id : 1
tags : ['scientist','biologist','mathematician','chemist'];

user_id : 1
tags : ['scientist','physicist','carpenter','chemist'];
```

I am query making api and the URL is something like this:

```
localhost:8080/tags=scientist,biologist // should return 1st document
```

or

```
localhost:8080/tags=physicist,carpenter // should return 2nd document
```

There can be any number of tags in the url and the tag array must contain all the tags present in the url.
How can I acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the query annotation which uses the **[`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or)** operator as

```
@Query("{'$or' : [{ 'tags': ?0, 'tags': ?1 }]}")
public List<Tags> findByTagsFirstorSecond(string firstTag, string secondTag);
```

Comment: '$or' can not be used as the tag array must contain all the input tags. and secondly the number of tags are not fixed. The input can be any number of tags

Comment: Such crucial information should have been included in the question in the first place.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question